# How to click Title in left side and will show the Detail in right side for Wordpresss

Tags: wordpress, elementor

How can I create a function like click the title in left side and will automatically show the detail in the right side. It using what plugin or short code in the Wordpress? Please give a suggestion,Thanks.

Comment: like this image: https://imgur.com/a/5Qo58wN

Comment: use this one and make your structure using customize :
https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-store-locator/

Comment: If I want only click the "Title" text in left side, and it will show the "Detail" in right side, can make it?

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will help you:

## It is just an Example:-

```
        <!DOCTYPE html>
        <html>
        <head>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <style>
        .details {display : none;width:50%;float:left;}
        .title{
        float: left;
        width:50%
         }
         .extra{width:100%;float:left;}
        </style>
        <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".title").click(function(){
         $('.details').hide();
          $(this).next().toggle();

        });
        });
        </script>
        </head>
        <body>
        <div class="extra">
        <div class="title">Title1</div>
        <div class="details">
        <p>This is a paragraph with little content.</p>
        <p>This is another small paragraph.</p>
        </div>
        </div>
        <div class="extra">
        <div class="title">Title2</div>
        <div class="details">
        <p>This is a paragraph with little content.</p>
        <p>This is another small paragraph.</p>
        </div>
        </div>
        <div class="extra">
        <div class="title">Title3</div>
        <div class="details">
        <p>This is a paragraph with little content.</p>
        <p>This is another small paragraph.</p>
        </div>
        </div>

        </body>
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for answering for my question and it works, but if i have a title 2 and 3, how it works to show content 2 and 3? Thanks

Comment: ok, thanks but if i want show the content that don't have spacing between the title. It can make it?